# Table in jsf having the same behavior as that of Excel API

Tags: jquery, jsf, jakarta-ee

I want to know if it's possible to get a table in Java EE which has the same behavior as that of Excel (if there is an API , Framwork etc) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to apply the same principle of Excel formula for my xhtml datatable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23957744/how-to-apply-the-same-principle-of-excel-formula-for-my-xhtml-datatable)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i apply all Excel functions to my JSF Table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23951227/how-can-i-apply-all-excel-functions-to-my-jsf-table)